# About Rutherford scattering

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, electrostatics, scattering, integration

I am trying to derive Rutherford's scattering formula, with the coordinate system and polar coordinates chosen as in the picture below.

[image]

Angular momentum conservation yields $mvb = mr^2 \dot{\varphi}$. I then tried to make use of this in Newton's equation along the $x$-direction
\begin{equation}
m \frac{\mathrm{d}v_x}{\mathrm{d}t} = F_x = \frac{2Ze^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0} \frac{\sin(\varphi) \dot{\varphi}}{bv}
\end{equation}
from the starting point on the left to the endpoint on the right-hand side with scattering angle $\theta$. Integrating over time gives
\begin{equation}
\int_{t_{\text{start}}}^{t_{\text{end}}} \frac{\mathrm{d}v_x}{\mathrm{d}t} \mathrm{d}t = \frac{2Ze^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0 mvb} \int_{t_{\text{start}}}^{t_{\text{end}}} \sin(\varphi)\dot{\varphi}\, \mathrm{d}t.
\end{equation}
Introducing substitutions results in
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{v\sin(\theta)}\, \mathrm{d}v_x = \frac{2Ze^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0 mvb} \int_{\pi}^{\theta} \sin(\varphi)\,\mathrm{d}\varphi,\\
v\sin(\theta) = -\frac{2Ze^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0 mvb} \left(1+\cos(\theta)\right).
\end{align}
At this point, I do not see where I made the mistake which led to the minus sign on the right-hand side. Taking a look at Rutherford's formula, it should not appear there. Does anybody see it? Any help is appreciated.

**My assumption:** With $\varphi$ chosen as in the picture, $\dot{\varphi}(t)$ is negative for all $t$. Then, the equation for the angular momentum conservation might also be written with an additional minus sign, as $mvb$ is positive, and both would cancel at the end. However, a formal derivation of $mr^2\dot{\varphi}$ does not lead to such an additional minus sign.

Comment: Which textbook are you following? Also, why are you assuming v=0 at t_start?

Comment: I am not particularly following a textbook as my definition of $\varphi$ is different from the standard literature (usually, $\varphi$ is measured to the negative $z$-axis in my picture and then integration is performed from 0 to $\pi-\theta$). However, my solution is geared to "Atom- und Quantenphysik" by Haken and Wolf (a German book).

Comment: Note that I am assuming the $x$-component of $v$ to be zero at $t_{\text{start}}$.

Comment: Notice that if you make theta -> -theta you recover the usual equation. Does that make any sense as to how you defined the other variables?

Comment: But $\theta$ should be positive when defining $\varphi$ like in the picture, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the mistake. Indeed, my assumption gave the correct hint: The term $mvb$ needs to have an additional minus sign. We have
\begin{equation}
\vec{L}_{\text{start}} = \vec{r}_{\text{start}}\times \vec{p}_{\text{start}} = (b\,\hat{e_x} - |z|\,\hat{e_z})\times mv\,\hat{e_z} = -mvb\,\hat{e_y}.
\end{equation}
All in all, angular momentum conservation reads
\begin{equation}
-mvb = L_y = mr^2\dot{\varphi}
\end{equation}
and the two minus signs cancel after the integration.